# RStudio: Knit to HTML occurs error: "Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed"

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am having a problem with RStudio (Version 1.1.456) and with R version 3.5.0 in my macOS Mojave.

When I am trying to convert R Markdown document to HTML, pdf or word, using knit option, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: [When in doubt, try to upgrade.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) In your case, the R version is not the latest. It happens that R 3.5.0 has a bad bug that might be relevant here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-April/075897.html

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and I updated R and RStudio. Unfortunately, the problem persists.